# how to return the latest records by timestamp grouped by key?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a data set that looks similar to this:

```
{"user":333,"product":943, "rating":2.025743791177902, "timestamp":1481675659}
{"user":333,"product":3074,"rating":2.1070657532324493,"timestamp":1481675178}
{"user":333,"product":3074,"rating":2.108323259636257, "timestamp":1481673546}
{"user":333,"product":943, "rating":2.0211849667268353,"timestamp":1481675178}
{"user":333,"product":943, "rating":2.041045323231024, "timestamp":1481673546}
{"user":333,"product":119, "rating":2.1832303461543163,"timestamp":1481675659}
{"user":333,"product":119, "rating":2.1937538029700203,"timestamp":1481673546}
{"user":111,"product":123, ...
```

I would like to query all records for a user (e.g. 333), but only return the latest timestamp for each product. E.g. based on the data above, the query would return:

```
{"user":333,"product":119, "rating":2.1832303461543163,"timestamp":1481675659}     
{"user":333,"product":3074,"rating":2.1070657532324493,"timestamp":1481675178}
{"user":333,"product":943, "rating":2.025743791177902, "timestamp":1481675659}
```

The equivalent sql query would look 'something' like this:

```
SELECT * FROM recommendations L
LEFT JOIN recommendations R ON
          L.user = R.user AND
          L.product = R.product AND
          L.timestamp < r.timestamp
WHERE isnull(r.user) and isnull(r.product)
```

Is this possible with a map/reduce index?  If so, how?  If not, is there an alternative approach such as lucene index?

Ideally I would also like to sort by the rating value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudant/CouchDB MapReduce can produce aggregate counts/sums/stats for compound keys e.g.

- the number entries grouped by user & product
- the average rating grouped by user & product

but it can't return you "the latest rating" grouped by user & product.

A Lucene-based index doesn't help much either. It would allow allow the selection of data in a time window e.g. "get my user ratings between timestamp X and timestamp Y that belong to user Z" but as Lucene-based indexes don't have aggregation functions, then would still have work to do in your app.

Another solution is to export your data to a data-warehousing solution like DashDB and perform your aggregating SQL query there.